# Spring: Get SessionRegistry without modifying any XML files?

Tags: xml, spring, session, javabeans

According to articles like [this one](http://java.dzone.com/articles/consider-replacing-spring-xml), it is possible to use Spring completely without modifying any xml files. So **without modifying any XML files**, I'm trying to get access to all currently logged in users with a `SessionRegistry` like it is done [here](http://krams915.blogspot.de/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html). What I have tried so far is, first of all, creating a Bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {   
[...]
    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
[...]
}
```

And then injecting the Bean in my controller:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @Resource(name = "sessionRegistry")
    private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/"})
    public String list() {
        List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    }
[...]
}
```

But whenever I print out `principals`, I just get an empty list. So my assumption would be, that probably, just creating the Bean the way I did isn't enough. But why? And do you have any advice on how to go on?

Comment: What is `SessionRegistryImpl`?

Comment: it's `org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl`

Comment: I believe that is a class that should be managed by Spring security, not by you. Obviously calling `getAllPrincipals` when you haven't added any will return an empty list.

Comment: Well I just followed this tutorial (http://krams915.blogspot.de/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html) where the class is used.

Comment: The tutorial seems to be doing a lot more than just declaring a `SessionRegistryImpl` bean. Have you done all of that? It seems to need a `ConcurrentSessionFilter` bean and a bunch of other configuration.

Comment: Well I've added all the beans but I don't know how to get the lines inside the `http` tag and the `listener` tag into my application without using xml.

Comment: I believe there is an annotation based configuration process with newer versions of Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure that you use the session repository in your Spring Security configuration. I'm guessing currently you are using a different instance of SessionRepository. For example:

```java
protected void configure(
        HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)

                // This line is important otherwise a default instance
                // will be used that is different than your Bean
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired");
}

@Bean
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

Next you need to ensure that HttpSessionEventPublisher is specified. This can be done using the following:

```java
public class SecurityInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also note that you will need to change your `@Resource` type to `SessionRegistry` rather than `SessionRegistryImpl`. For example:

```java
@Resource(name = "sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```